# Can you publish a public IP route over a Windows RRAS VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rras

I'm trying to direct traffic to a public IP range to travel over our VPN without redirecting all traffic over the VPN.

I've added the IP via RRAS > VPN > IPv4 > Static Routes however, the public IP route does not appear to publish to the VPN clients.

Is this possible to do? If so, what am I doing wrong on the server? This is where the private IP routes are published so I'd think public IP routes would go there as well.

Per the request, additional details are being added below:

I'm trying to publish a static route to 1.2.3.4 /19 to route over the VPN for clients that connect to our RRAS VPN. I've tried to add this via the static route function mentioned previously but it does not appear to push out to clients when they connect like it does for the private routes (such as 10.0.0.0 /8).

**Note:** I don't need to know how to setup split tunneling, we already have this in place. I just need to know how to push a public IP range to route over the VPN path.

Answer (score 0):

Selectively routing traffic over a VPN is called split-tunneling. Your question could benefit from a bit more detail, or the caveats when answering become so many.

Perhaps you are looking for a way of inserting these networks into the client side routing tables (you need to describe your usecase)?

Then you could script the routing table entries on the clients yourself, or use [CMAK](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rrasblog/archive/2007/06/11/split-tunnelling-using-cmak.aspx) to the same split-tunneling effect.

Comment: I thought I made it pretty clear already but I suppose not. I've added more specific details to my question per your request.